# Cache model for often requesting items

Tags: azure, caching, azure-service-fabric

I have a bunch of user-generated messages with timestamps, text messages, profile images respectively and other stuff. All clients (phones) who are using my Web API are able to request last messages then scroll them down and request oldest items. Obviously, top messages are hottest data in whole list. Obviously, I want to make a cache, which has caching policy and clear undestanding about new requested messages - are requsted messages hot, or not?

I created a stateless service with MemoryCache and now use it for my purposes. Is there are any underwater stones which I should take into account during my work with it? Except point, of course, that I have five nodes, and user is able to make a request to service which has no cache inside. In that case this service goes to data-layer-service then gets and loads some data from it.

### UPD #1

Forgot mention that this list of messages updates time out of time with new entries.

### UPD #2

I wrapped `MemoryCache` in `IReliableDictionary` implementation and palm off it under a stateful Service with my own StateManager implementation. Every time a request didn't find an item in the collection I go to the Azure Storage and retrieve actual data. After I had finished I realized that my experiment is not useful because there is no way for scaling such approach. I mean if my app has fixed partitioned Reliable Services working as cache, I do not have possibility to grow them up with upscaling my Service Fabric. In case of load increase after some time this fact hits me in my face :)

I still do not know how to make a cache for my super hot most readable messages more efficient way. And I still doubt in Reliable Actors approach. It creates a huge amount of replicated data.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an ideal use of an actor.

The actor will be garbage collected after a period of time, so data won't stay in memory.

One actor per user.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution for the first view. But it means that I should replicate small pieces of my messages list many times for tons of users instead of creating some kind of common service with cache which able to handle users requests in parallel with predefined cache policy. Better accumulate data in one place than in many, or not? Especially if we are talking about cache.

Comment: In some ways this is what actors are supposed to do. The problem with having a single cache is that it will ultimately require sharding in order to scale. Starting with the actor model means one actor per user. Sharding and scaling then just works. You could also use each actor to manage the messages for each user as well.

Comment: Ok, maybe I forgot mention that the list of messages updats time out of time with new entries. In that case, I should notify actors (which already cached items) that data has been changed, or make a small timeout for actor caching. At last case it seems like people can not get actual data some time until next unique request for updates. And I assume that it is incorrect behaviour. Much more better to create concentrated place (memory cache as I described below) and only it decides if data is actual or not.

Comment: It may be your exact use case may require a centralised cache - but to be honest, nothing I'm seeing in how you've explained it leads me to that conclusion. The actor model can lead to thinking about this differently which may be why. Have a look at some of the akka and Orleans documentation as well  - it may give you a different way to think about solving your problem

Comment: If you give me some references it would be nice. Thank you for your kind. Becasue I am still not sure this is an effective way of using actor per user model in described situation. But I would like to read about it more anyway.

Comment: Maybe I would like to have an approach if Service Fabric had some extra functionality for using Reliable Collections as cache. But items in RC do not have life timeout functionality as I know. May be thats a good way for RC evolution, I do not know actually :)

Comment: Just remember that actors sit on top of reliable collections. I would recommend try having an actor for each user and see how that goes. It may turn out to be what you want. Re the previous comment, look at http://getakka.net/ and https://github.com/dotnet/orleans

Comment: @eli-arbel that was my next question. Yesterday I tried to create kind of stateless actor which doesn't have any state and works only like a proxy for service. I though if I set attribute Persistence.None - it dies after operation finished, but no. I had to delete it with manual deletion. But never mind, it does not make sense to current topic. Thank you for your input.